# How to use column name dynamically inside insert query in djnago

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views

```
cursor.execute("insert into demoapp_site ('name','firstname','lastname') values (%s,%s,%s)",site_data)
```

in above query I want to pass column name dynamically and %s which is inside values also not predefine that how many times it need to write

so, how can I write my sql query according to my data which comes from html table in 2d array from??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to build the query before using it. As follows

```
field_string = ""
value_string = ""

# This will string in this format "'field1','field2'"
# Assuming array is in format [["field1", "value1"],..]
# Update the for loop statement based on your input, other lines remain same 
for field, value in my_field_array:
    temp_field_string = "'%s'" % field
    field_string = field_string + temp_field_string + ","
    temp_value_string = "'%s'" % value
    value_string = value_string + temp_value_string + ","

# Removing trailing comma's before passing the values
cmd = "insert into demoapp_site (%s) values (%s)" % (field_string[:-1], value_string[:-1])
cursor.execute(cmd)
```